# Is it safe to update counter from inside one of Promise.all promises in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, race-condition

Node.js [uses](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) threads from worker pool to perform I/O operations. If I need to count the number of characters in many files concurrently (using `Promise.all`), is it safe to update the `totalNumberOfChars` variable which is common to all promisifed file read operations? Because a separate thread may be used for each read operation can `totalNumberOfChars` be incorrect?

This is the code:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

/**
 * 
 * @param {Array} pathsToFiles - array of paths to files
 */
const main = async (pathsToFiles) => {
  let totalNumberOfChars = 0;
  await Promise.all(
    pathsToFiles.map(async (path) => {
      const chars = await readFileAsync(path);
      totalNumberOfChars += chars.length;
    })
  );
  console.log("totalNumberOfChars", totalNumberOfChars);
};

main(['/home/a.txt', '/home/b.txt'])
```

Comment: The map doesn't return anything?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it returns a promise implicitly but `map` is used just to enable async operations to be used in a loop

Comment: Ah the return value is implied by `async`

Comment: I would assume the operation is safe since the outer function waits for all promises to be fulfilled/rejected before logging `totalNumberOfChars`. The main issue I see is what happens if one of the promises rejects/throws?

Comment: @evolutionxbox even if we assume that all promises resolve and there're no errors, the counter is potentially updated by multiple worker threads.

Comment: What threads? JavaScript is single threaded. `promise.all` doesn't make it multi-threaded. For that you need to [use web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe, because what's inside this function:

```
pathsToFiles.map(async (path) => {
    const chars = await readFileAsync(path);
    totalNumberOfChars += chars.length;
})
```

is executed synchronously, meaning that your file is read synchronously (again, inside that callback!) and you're adding to counter synchronously as well. So after the "main" function's execution you'll receive the right answer.